PySpark GroupedData - chain several different aggregation methods
I am playing with GroupedData in pyspark.
This is my environment.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.5.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.18, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.24
Branch HEAD

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.html
I wonder if the following is possible.
Say I want to use only the methods of GroupedData, and not import any functions from pyspark.sql.functions.
OK, suppose I have some DataFrame and I've grouped it already by column A and I've got a GroupedData object back.
Now I want to do on my GroupedData object say sum(column B), and say avg(column C) and maybe min(column D) in one shot or via chained method calls.
Can I do this just by using GroupedData methods?
I am asking this because it seems that once I've done sum(column B), I don't have a GroupedData object anymore, and so I cannot continue to chain any GroupedData methods further.
So is that (what I have in mind) possible or not?
If it's possible, how can we do it?

I do not think that this is possible.
Looking at the source of GroupedData, we see that all functions like

avg
max
min and
sum

return a DataFrame, so chaining is not possible.

OK, thanks, so it looked to me too. I just wanted to make sure I am not missing or misunderstanding something.

In code they provide some base examples doc
You can use the .agg(sf.sum(df.B).as("sumB"), sf.avg(df.C).as("avgC"))
Examples:
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2, "Alice"), (3, "Alice"), (5, "Bob"), (10, "Bob")], ["age", "name"])
df.show()
+---+-----+
|age| name|
+---+-----+
|  2|Alice|
|  3|Alice|
|  5|  Bob|
| 10|  Bob|
+---+-----+

Group-by name, and count each group.

df.groupBy(df.name)
GroupedData[grouping...: [name...], value: [age: bigint, name: string], type: GroupBy]

df.groupBy(df.name).agg({"*": "count"}).sort("name").show()
+-----+--------+
| name|count(1)|
+-----+--------+
|Alice|       2|
|  Bob|       2|
+-----+--------+

Group-by name, and calculate the minimum age.

df.groupBy(df.name).agg(sf.min(df.age)).sort("name").show()
+-----+--------+
| name|min(age)|
+-----+--------+
|Alice|       2|
|  Bob|       5|
+-----+--------+

Same as above but uses pandas UDF.

@pandas_udf('int', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)  # doctest: +SKIP
def min_udf(v):
    return v.min()
df.groupBy(df.name).agg(min_udf(df.age)).sort("name").show()  # doctest: +SKIP
+-----+------------+
| name|min_udf(age)|
+-----+------------+
|Alice|           2|
|  Bob|           5|
+-----+------------+


OK, thanks... I was able to do it that way too, so this approach is quite useful. But my question is if I can do it just with the sum, avg, min methods of the GroupedData object itself?

.sum, .min, other methods ask a single aggregation process, the more times you call it individually, the more times spark will process aggregation the same data and then just multiplying group by calls instead of doing only 1 group by operation and then locally compute several aggregations
